# pyright not autocompleting dlib for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, dlib, coc.nvim, pyright

Specs:

- Mac M1 Pro
- Dlib installed with conda (also tried pip3 and it gave the same results)
- Vscode and coc.nvim using pyright (both using the same language server)
- python 3.9.12

```py
import dlib

dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
```

Currently, when I run the above script with python, **it works** with no hiccups, but when I try to autocomplete the modules of dlib in VScode or in vim (using coc.nvim) **it will not autocomplete** the modules of `dlib`.

Answer (score 0):

It's Pyright's issue, Pyright needs type stub files to work.

Comment: Yes.  How do I generate a stubs file for dlib which can be read by the pyright language server?  

This I arrived at this problem and generating a type stub file for this library continues to only give [the stubs which are in this file](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/tools/python/dlib/__init__.py.in) which are not helpful at all.

[link to dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib)